# IIS 6 .NET MVC web app deployment - need to achieve a specific URL structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6

I need my local (testing) deployment to respond to a URL like

```
    http://localhost/apps.mydomain.com/myappname
```

not

```
    http://localhost/myappname
```

Long story as to why but I just need that to be the case.

I actually had this working for awhile but I can't remember how.  I had to delete and add the site again and now can't figure out what combination of settings gave me the result.

How can I achieve that URL structure locally?

**MORE INFO:**  I've created a website called "apps.mydomain.com".  I then added an application under that site with the alias "myappname".  This app can be invoked with URL

```
    http://localhost/myappname
```

Why?  What happened to "apps.mydomain.com"?  When I add it...

```
    http://localhost/apps.mydomain.com/myappname
```

I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create directories apps.mydomain.com and apps.mydomain.com\myappname under C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

Or, if you don't want to publish your application in wwwroot, you can create virtual directory in IIS.

Comment: Hmmm...  Tried the virtual directory thing.  I obviously don't have it right though.  Wouldn't the alias need to be "apps.mydomain.com/myappname"?  Not acceptable due to special characters, but without the site name the alias doesn't work.  Not sure why creating a site called apps.mydomain.com and adding an app under that site with alias myappname doesn't work.  Thought that would generate URL structure "site name/alias". No dice.  Is site name irrelevant in the URL structure when I add an app to a site?  What is site name's relation to the URL structure?

Comment: May be you want use address `http://apps.mydomain.com/myappname` instead `http://localhost/apps.mydomain.com/myappname`?

Comment: You can do it using text file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and host headers in IIS 6.

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: No dice.  No matter the configuration, the url - http://localhost/apps.mydomain.com/myappname returns 404.  If I take apps.mydomain.com out the app tries to run but fails.  That tells me it is found at least.  It fails though because some internal libraries require that apps.mydomain.com appear in the URL.  Frustrating because I did have this working well for about the past year.  I did nothing to host files etc. Just added website and app to local IIS.  Question still remains.  Why does the site name (apps.mydomain.com) get dropped from the URL? What's the function of the site name?